# Error when trying to see my site in PythonAnywhere

Tags: django, pythonanywhere, secret-key

I've put my site in PythonAnywhere, but when I try to see it through the browser, it's generated an error. It has something to do with the secret key. In the project (created in pycharm), the secret key is stored in a .env file, and in PythonAnywhere, the secret key is stored in an environment variable in the .profile file.

Here's how the .profile file is now:

```
# Ensures bash settings are also loaded when using SSH access
source ~/.bashrc
export SECRET_KEY='django_secret_key'
```

Here's the log error:

```
2022-05-01 20:55:38,286: Error running WSGI application
2022-05-01 20:55:38,303: decouple.UndefinedValueError: SECRET_KEY not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.
2022-05-01 20:55:38,303:   File "/var/www/ezaublog_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 15, in <module>
2022-05-01 20:55:38,303:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2022-05-01 20:55:38,304: 
2022-05-01 20:55:38,304:   File "/home/ezaublog/.virtualenvs/ezaublog.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2022-05-01 20:55:38,304:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2022-05-01 20:55:38,304: 
2022-05-01 20:55:38,304:   File "/home/ezaublog/.virtualenvs/ezaublog.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2022-05-01 20:55:38,305:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2022-05-01 20:55:38,305: 
2022-05-01 20:55:38,305:   File "/home/ezaublog/.virtualenvs/ezaublog.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
2022-05-01 20:55:38,305:     self._setup(name)
2022-05-01 20:55:38,305: 
2022-05-01 20:55:38,305:   File "/home/ezaublog/.virtualenvs/ezaublog.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
2022-05-01 20:55:38,305:     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2022-05-01 20:55:38,305: 
2022-05-01 20:55:38,306:   File "/home/ezaublog/.virtualenvs/ezaublog.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
2022-05-01 20:55:38,306:     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2022-05-01 20:55:38,306: 
2022-05-01 20:55:38,306:   File "/home/ezaublog/ezaublog.pythonanywhere.com/mysite/settings.py", line 25, in <module>
2022-05-01 20:55:38,306:     SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')
2022-05-01 20:55:38,306: 
2022-05-01 20:55:38,306:   File "/home/ezaublog/.virtualenvs/ezaublog.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/decouple.py", line 243, in __call__
2022-05-01 20:55:38,306:     return self.config(*args, **kwargs)
2022-05-01 20:55:38,306: 
2022-05-01 20:55:38,306:   File "/home/ezaublog/.virtualenvs/ezaublog.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/decouple.py", line 105, in __call__
2022-05-01 20:55:38,307:     return self.get(*args, **kwargs)
2022-05-01 20:55:38,307: 
2022-05-01 20:55:38,307:   File "/home/ezaublog/.virtualenvs/ezaublog.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/decouple.py", line 90, in get
2022-05-01 20:55:38,307:     raise UndefinedValueError('{} not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.'.format(option))
2022-05-01 20:55:38,307: ***************************************************
2022-05-01 20:55:38,307: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2022-05-01 20:55:38,307: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug: 
2022-05-01 20:55:38,307: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2022-05-01 20:55:38,308: ***************************************************
```

Here's part of my setting.py file. It shows how the SECRET_KEY is read from the environment variable:

```
from pathlib import Path
from decouple import config


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')
```

You can see through the log that I'm using the python-decouple package. And when I open a terminal in the host (PythonAnywhere), I can see the environment variable that's storing the secret key through the `printenv variable_name` or `echo $variable_name` commands. Even so, it seems django can't see the environment variable to recover the secret key.

Note: I didn't touch the wsgi.py file.

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: The error message says you haven't defined the environment variable.  Please copy in your code (and the error message) _as_ _text_, NOT as a screenshot.  We need to see where you're setting the environment variable and how you're reading it. It may also be helpful to review https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/environment-variables-for-web-apps/ (and to confirm you've tried what's recommended there.)

Comment: @SarahMesser Thanks for responding. I made some updates to the post following what you said. I think it's best formatted and explains more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved. The problem was Django wasn't seeing the environment variable that was storing the secret key (you can easily see that in the error log I posted in the question). All I needed to do was to create a .env file in the project's directory in the host (PythonAnywhere) to store the key, and then the site begun to work.

@SarahMesser posted in a comment a [link](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/environment-variables-for-web-apps/) from the PythonAnywhere help pages demonstrating how to do it. It's worth mention that the only thing I needed to do was to create this .env file. I didn't have to change the code to use the *python-dotenv* package that is mentioned in the help pages (I still used the *python-decouple*, and it worked) nor use a *postactivate* script.

Even though the site is working now, I didn't understand why Django couldn't see the environment variable I have created in the .profile file, but maybe this is a problem outside the post's scope.